# How to do the Hot fix deployment for the nifi-famework generated war file- NiFi

Tags: deployment, apache-nifi

Can anyone suggest how to do the hot fix deployment for the nifi-famework generated war file.

I would like to make some css and js changes in nifi-web-ui under the nifi-nar-bundles and want the new build should be copied automatically each time i do the changes , to my nifi-assembly/target/...(parent directory).

Is there a way for an auto deployment, without doing the maven build everytime which is consuming a lot of time and how my latest changes can be reflected everytime without doing the build

I am trying to copy from

nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-framework-bundle/nifi-framework/nifi-web/nifi-web-ui/target/nifi-web-ui-1.8.0-SNAPSHOT.war

to

nifi-assembly/target/nifi-1.8.0-SNAPSHOT-bin/nifi-1.8.0-SNAPSHOT/work/jetty/nifi-web-ui-1.8.0-SNAPSHOT.war